# How force 32 processes to run on 32 different cores?

Tags: parallel-processing, operating-system, multiprocessing, multicore

I am running a **simulation** of a **many-core system**. I have a benchmark which has an option of selecting the number of processes as an option. This is set to 32.

Now when I run this bench mark, it correctly produces 32 processes.
**Sample :**

[image]

Now I want to force it to run on 32 cores. For this I have tried :

NOTE : I am running my application through busybox.

```
./busybox taskset 0xFFFFFFFF ./fmm <input
```

Here `fmm` is the benchmark I am running.

This whole system is being run in a simulator called qsim and when I run this, the processes get attached to only one or two cores (18th and 19th).

**I understand that the mask is only an indicator to the OS that it can run on the given cores, but is there any way to force the OS to run the 32 processes on 32 cores ?**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try to set CPU affinity och each thread.